Error "Cannot modify an evaluated object originating in an imported file" when trying remove Maui references
I'm getting the below error when trying to remove references for Microsoft.Maui.Controls (8.0.7) and Microsoft.Maui.Controls (8.0.7) in my new .Net MAUI app.

I want to remove them because they're throwing warnings and don't have a proper path. See below.

This MAUI references issue started when I tried upgrading one of our iOS projects to .Net 8 and it impacted even previously working .Net 8 projects too.
I tried to reinstall Nuget packages for MAUI (didn't install at all), MAUI SDKs, dotnet workloads for all platforms (though this failed for Advertising manifest), repaired VS 2022, tried all the related suggestions on the internet, but nothing worked out.
Looking for help to resolve the Maui references issue, especially "Cannot modify dialog".

The solution to your migration issues is not to try remove mandatory packages, try instead to update and restore nuget packages.

@Cfun Thanks for your comment but that's the first things that I tried

I had to install the entire MAUI workload to fix it: "dotnet workload install maui"
